# Enum lookup by passing 2 parameters

Tags: java

How can I get the enum by passing the fruit and vegetable parameter.

```
public enum EnumType {
        A("Apple", "Asparagus"),
        B("Banana", "Brocolli"),
        C("Candy", "Carrot");

    public final String fruit;
    public final String vegetable;

    EnumType(String fruit, String vegetable) {
        this.fruit= fruit;
        this.vegetable= vegetable;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `valueOf()` , e.g. `fruits.valueOf()` basically getting the right value ?

Comment: for example i want to get A. so i need to pass Apple and Asparagus

Comment: `valueOf` won't work here as you would have to pass it "A", "B" or "C".  You will need to provide a method that loops through the possible values looking for the one that matches your input.

Comment: What should happen if you search for ("Apple", "Brocolli") ?

Comment: Put a private static `Map<String, EnumType>` field within the enum and fill it (in a static block) with e.g. the concatenation of instance variables as key and instance itself as value. Then write a public static method that takes two `String` parameters (e.g., "Apple" and "Asparagus") and gets the instance from the map.

Comment: @Alex I need it to set to something if what enum it is.

Answer (score 2):

This would have to be achieved by iterating through and comparing the `fruit` and `vegetable` members. So something like:

```
EnumType find(String fruit, String vegetable) {

    for (EnumType t : EnumType.values()) {
        
        if(t.fruit.equals(fruit) && t.vegetable.equals(vegetable)) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your enum is alphabetized, you could reference it using fruit.charAt(0).toUpperCase() to get the first letter of the fruit. Then (I think) you can use valueOf() to reference the row corresponding to that letter. Please correct me if I'm wrong—I'm relatively new to enums.

Comment: thats a really big if and it requires the client site to know about the internal structure of the enum, I am not convinced that is a good idea :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static EnumType ofFruit(String fruit) {
    for (EnumType e : values()) {}
        if (e.fruit.equals(fruit)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
    // or throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such enum constant");
}


public static EnumType ofVegetable(String vegetable) {
    for (EnumType e : values()) {}
        if (e.vegetable.equals(vegetable)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
    // or throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such enum constant");
}

public static EnumType ofFruitAndVegetable(String fruit, String vegetable) {
    for (EnumType e : values()) {
        if (e.fruit.equals(fruit) && e.vegetable.equals(vegetable)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
    // or throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such enum constant");
}
```

depending on what exactly you need.